# Почему после рестарта сервиса Elk перестает писать логи?

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Имеется стэк ELK в него сервисы пишут логи. Схема стандартая сервисы пишут в логстэш , логстэш передает в эластик, Кибана отображает логи.

Проблема появляется когда один из сервисов перезапускается или обновляется, после этого в Кибане видны логи только этого сервиса. Логи от остальных сервисов не отображаются.
Перезапуск логстэш не помогает. Если перезапустить все сервисы то их логи становится видны.

В чем может быть проблема ? Сервисы расположены на разных серверах, стоят отдельно от ELK.

UPD:

config logstash:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => "5000"
    type => syslog
    codec => json
  }
}

filter {
    if [logger_name] =~ "metrics" {
        kv {
            source => "message"
            field_split_pattern => ", "
            prefix => "metric_"
        }
        mutate {
            convert => { "metric_value" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_count" => "integer" }
            convert => { "metric_min" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_max" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_mean" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_stddev" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_median" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_p75" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_p95" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_p98" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_p99" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_p999" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_mean_rate" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_m1" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_m5" => "float" }
            convert => { "metric_m15" => "float" }
            # No need to keep message field after it has been parsed
            remove_field => ["message"]
     }
    }
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "instance_name" => "%{app_name}-%{host}:%{app_port}" }
        }
    }

}

output {
    if [logger_name] =~ "metrics" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["1.2.4.12:9200"]
            index => "metrics-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
      else {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["1.2.4.12:9200"]
            index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

Приложения сконфигурированы на logstash. Настройки берут из consul. Настройки следующие:

```
logging:
  path: logs
  archive-path: archive
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    ru.renue.obed: DEBUG
    ru.renue.aud.layout: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig: WARN
    io.github.jhipster: DEBUG
    ru.renue.eps.cryptoservice: DEBUG
    ru.renue.eps.monitoring: INFO
    com.zaxxer.hikari: DEBUG
    org.springframework.jms: DEBUG
  logstash:
    enabled: true
    host: 1.2.4.12
    port: 5000
    queue-size: 512
```

Comment: Без предоставления всех данных, как настроен ELK, как сконфигурированы приложения на logstash и т.д. - вряд ли что-то можно сказать.

Comment: Потому, что что-то перестало работать в силу определенных обстоятельств.

Comment: Добавил конфиги логстэша и то как сервис находит его.